# For loop: Parsing XML by ElementTree Python3

Tags: python, xml

I designed this simplified XML file that is very similar to the XML file I'll have to parse. I'm trying to parse the text from the following nodes(Food, Date, ItemCondition, Amount)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Region>
  <District>
    <Store>
      <Department>
        <Produce>        
          <Food>Apple</Food>
        </Produce>
      </Department>
      <ProductInfo>
        <BoxofFruit>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          </Qualifiers>        
          <Date>101214</Date>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>19.99</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>          
          </Price>       
        </BoxofFruit>
        <BoxofFruit>
          <Qualifiers>
            <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          </Qualifiers>        
          <Date>091114</Date>
          <Price>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>21.99</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>          
          </Price>       
        </BoxofFruit>     
      </ProductInfo>
    </Store>
  </District>
</Region>
```

For the life of me I cant seem to get the Food text.  Heres my current code that works as long as I dont include the Food portion.

```
Fruit = root.findall('.//BoxofFruit')
for Apple in Fruit:
    Date = Apple.find('Date').text
    Condition = Apple.find('Qualifiers/ItemCondition').text
    Price = Apple.find('Price/LandedPrice/Amount').text
    print(Date, Condition, Price)
```

Here's what I receive from my code:

```
101214 New 19.99
091114 New 21.99
```

And here is an example of what I would like to see:

```
Apple 101214 New 19.99
Apple 091114 New 21.99
```

Ive been fumbling with this for days.  I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Is a `store` always selling only one item? What happens if you "include the Food portion"?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Food` is not in `BoxofFruit`, you have to fetch it beforehand. For example:

```
fruit = root.find('.//Food').text
for Apple in root.findall('.//BoxofFruit')
    Date = Apple.find('Date').text
    Condition = Apple.find('Qualifiers/ItemCondition').text
    Price = Apple.find('Price/LandedPrice/Amount').text
    print(fruit, Date, Condition, Price)
```